# Error running jar file using file with JavaFX

Tags: java, maven, jar, io

I need to create a jar file based on my project which has files to read. But when I run such jar by double click nothing works, but if I run it through command line in java -jar.jar format the following error occurs:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: HashSetFile.txt
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at myproject.JavaFXBuild.getListFile(JavaFXBuild.java:378)
        at myproject.JavaFXController.initialize(JavaFXController.java:364)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2446)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2414)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:185)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the build file:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
     <execution>
      <goals>
       <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
    <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
    <mainClass>
     uip.gui.JavaFxRun
    </mainClass>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the code that is complaining about:

```
public static void getListFile(String fileName, Set<String> stringSet) {
        try {
            **InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName));**
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                stringSet.add(line);
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "ERROR ", e);
        }
    }
```

I need to read data from a file line by line and put it into a HashSet. But when I try to run the JAR file, the following error occurs. In this case, the application starts itself, but the data is not loaded

Comment: That's a very clear exception - you don't have a file called `HashSetFile.txt` in the current working directory of your application. You need to work out where it really is, and adjust the current working directory or change the path you read accordingly, or if the file is not changing you could load it from inside the jar with it's resource path.